# method post in <a href> method post

Tags: php, mysql, href

Is there a way to replicate this in `<a href="blah.php">`?

```
<form action="http://localhost/php/suburb_added.php" method="post">
<b>Add a New Suburb</b>
<p>Name:
<input type="text" name="suburb" size="30" value="" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</p>
</form>
```

in suburb_added.php... i have this to capture

```
if (!empty($_POST['suburb']))
```

To a table form....

```
<td align="left"><a href="suburb_added.php"><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
```

how to create the items below from a table? The goal is when I click the result from `<?php echo $row['id'];?>`, I should be able to get the value of "id" and process it in suburb_added.php using similar to `if (!empty($_POST['suburb']))`

```
<form action="http://localhost/php/suburb_added.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="suburb" size="30" value="" />
```

Comment: You could have the `a` trigger a AJAX request that process via the POST method.

Answer (score 0):

what do you whant i don't understand?? I can help you

```
 <?php
 if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
 ?>
 <form action="" method="post" name="submit">
 <b>Add a New Suburb</b>
 <p>Name:
 <input type="text" name="suburb" size="30" value="" />
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
 </p>
 </form>
<?php
} else {
//paste here your code from http://localhost/php/suburb_added.php
echo "you doing post in this page.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Basically I have a working php query which displays the basic information in a table (below)...


>    ID number  Item Name  Category           Brand
>   1           Iphone          Electronics  Generic

I am trying to create a link using html and php to extract more detailed information from mysql when the user clicks "1".

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!--Try using header

like this:-->

if($_POST)  
{  
  header('location:login-form.php');  
}
else
{
  echo "";
}
```

Comment: if you want to display row use $_SESSION variables

Answer (score 0):

Change the PHP script so it uses `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`. This variable combines the contents of `$_POST` and `$_GET`. Then you can have a link like

```
<a href="suburb_added.php?suburb=<?php echo urlencode($row['name']) ?>"><?php echo $row['id'] ?></a>
```